# Google Map marker using JSON. Only the last marker in the loop is displayed on the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps

I am loading some marker information using JSON (Local file) but for some reason, only the last marker in the loop is showing on the map.

I can see all coordinates being printed correctly in the console so I am pretty sure the loop is fine, and most of the code is fine.

```
<script>
  function myMap() {

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("content_map" );
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.812757, -4.195363),
            zoom: 5,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            styles: [
                  {
                    "elementType": "geometry",

                    "stylers": [
                      {
                        "color": "#f5f5f5"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elementType": "labels.icon",
                    "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "off"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#616161"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#f5f5f5"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#bdbdbd"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#eeeeee"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi",
                                "elementType": "labels.text",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#757575"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.business",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.park",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#e5e5e5"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.park",
                                "elementType": "labels.text",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.park",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#0d99ba"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#ffffff"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#757575"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.highway",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.highway",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.highway",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#616161"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.local",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "off"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.local",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "off"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.local",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "transit.line",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#e5e5e5"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "transit.station",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#eeeeee"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "water",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#0d99ba"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "water",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
        };
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+

        '<img src="./img/logo_img_map.png" alt="">'+
        '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });


        $.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {



            for (i = 0; i < json.ChargeDevice.length; i++) { 

                addMarker(json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Latitude,json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Longitude);
                console.log(json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Latitude, json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Longitude);
            };


            function addMarker(lat,lng) {

                    var image = './img/logo_img_map.png';
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                        map: map,
                        icon: image
                    });

            };




      });

    };

  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY"></script>
```

I have looked through tons of threads now, but I cannot quite figure out why it doesnt work in this instance. I am running through my function as it happens in the loop... so really should the marker not remain?

Note: MY API key has been removed so it doesnt show online, but it does work on my webserver and the map loads fine. Really only one marker showing while I have 2 data sets in my JSON file.

I havent yet done the click envet either, but I dont think that matters for now does it?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried calling addmarker() method with timeout? let me know if not?

Comment: No I haven't. Not being an expert in with JS, I have limited debugging options... Would that help in pinpointing a potential issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think perhaps the problem is that you are declaring a new map for each marker. I would declare the map once, and reference it for each marker.

Try the following:

```
<script>
  function myMap() {

        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("content_map" );
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.812757, -4.195363),
            zoom: 5,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            styles: [
                  {
                    "elementType": "geometry",

                    "stylers": [
                      {
                        "color": "#f5f5f5"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elementType": "labels.icon",
                    "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "off"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#616161"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#f5f5f5"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#bdbdbd"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#eeeeee"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi",
                                "elementType": "labels.text",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#757575"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.business",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.park",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#e5e5e5"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.park",
                                "elementType": "labels.text",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "poi.park",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#0d99ba"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#ffffff"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#757575"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.highway",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.highway",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "on"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.highway",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#616161"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.local",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "off"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.local",
                                "elementType": "labels",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "visibility": "off"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "road.local",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "transit.line",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#e5e5e5"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "transit.station",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#eeeeee"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "water",
                                "elementType": "geometry",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#0d99ba"
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "featureType": "water",
                                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                                "stylers": [
                                  {
                                    "color": "#9e9e9e"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+

        '<img src="./img/logo_img_map.png" alt="">'+
        '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: contentString
        });


        $.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {



            for (var i = 0; i < json.ChargeDevice.length; i++) { 

                addMarker(json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Latitude,json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Longitude);
                console.log(json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Latitude, json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Longitude);
            };


            function addMarker(lat,lng) {

                    var image = './img/logo_img_map.png';
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                        map: map,
                        icon: image
                    });

            };




      });

    };

  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY"></script>
```

Comment: That is now working!!!!!!!

I cannot thank you enough for this help! Thanks a lot!!!!... I feel a bit silly now that it was something like that!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop with below code and check if it works. I have not tested it so please share if you see something changed in your console.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < json.ChargeDevice.length; i++) { 

    setTimeout(function(){
addMarker(json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Latitude,json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Longitude)

    console.log(json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Latitude, json.ChargeDevice[i].ChargeDeviceLocation.Longitude);
                };
    },i*200);
```

Comment: First thanks for your help.

I have tried your code - I had to amend the syntax a bit -  but now my JSON values are creating errors for some reasons...

I guess the timeout would be to see if the markers are on top of each other?